# Graphical hiccups in C# User Control - Resize obscures components

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm experiencing difficulty with a custom-made User Control, and my searching on Stack Overflow, MSDN, and Google didn't pop up any troubles quite like the one I'm experiencing.

I have a very simple User Control: It's a label, a text box, and a button, with a SaveFileDialog and a FolderSelectDialog available. The text box and button are anchored Left,Right and Right respectively, with the intent that if the control is resized larger, the text box will enlarge to fill the gap, and the button will stay on the right edge of the control.

The problem I am encountering is that when the control is enlarged, the area to the right of the default width of the control becomes blank space when the project is built and run. The pictures here will illustrate what I mean:

In editor:

[image: in editor]

Running:

[image: running]

The control is smallish in its design window, but when I add it to a form and widen it, it behaves as intended. However, when I run the form the control was added to, half the control isn't visible.

I suspect that I'm overlooking something fairly straightforward, but I wasn't able to find anything addressing this point in my search. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've inlined the images for you.

Comment: Use Spy++'s "Find Window" feature.  As you drag the cursor around your app, it'll identify, highlight (With a red box) and detail all the controls.  It should tell you both how large your edit box really is, and what is (if anything) covering things up.

Comment: @John Thank you for that tip - I hadn't used Spy++ before, it's good to know it exists. Unfortunately, though, when I move my mouse over the grayed-out portion where the right half of the text-box ought to be, it identifies that as the top-level form, and there's no apparent indication of another object 'covering' my control.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is a panel or something that is added to your control and will be brought to front somehow runtime.

from property window's top there's a combo from which you can select all the controls in your User Control.

check if all the controls are what you want.

if you find that panel or anything delete it :)

EDIT:
alright this was not your problem.

now I can only assume that you have set some manual sizes to your user control, i.e. in its constructor. in that case designer will show the correct size of you user control,

now some other place in your code, you have set the user controls size manually again. if the layout is suspended and size changes, I think that the anchored controls' size will not change automatically.

if this is your problem, it is probably hard to find.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I double-checked my control, and the text box, label, and button are the only objects in my control, and the user control was the only object on the form when I tested it.

Comment: @kaldrenon Something like a panel is covering the control.  Try looking around your form for something.

Comment: Thanks for the additional advice - I looked through the code for the control, though, and I don't manually set the sizes. There are, of course, calls to set the size in the .Designer code, but that's auto-generated and behaves normally.